# How to use custom UIView subclass in XIB editor with Monotouch?

Tags: interface-builder, xamarin.ios, xib

I have added a XIB based `UIViewController` to my solution and dragged some `UIViews` into it.
Now I want some of the views not to be `UIView` but `RoundedRectView` 
(https://github.com/Krumelur/RoundedRectView) which inherits from `UIView`.

How to achieve this? I tried to change the class in Interface Builder but that did nothing. Then I manually modified the designer.cs file but that resulted in a failure.
Then I tried modifying the fake ObjC code but that failed too.

(I'm using Xcode 4.2 and MD 2.8.6.4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your view subclass needs at least two things:

1. Register attribute

   `[Register("MyView")]`

   `public class MyView : UIView {}`
2. IntPtr constructor

   `public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}`

You then open the XIB in Interface Builder, add a `UIView` and set its Class in the Identity Inspector to the name you passed to the Register attribute. When you connect it to an outlet, you will see that it has the correct type.

[image: Outlet with correct type]

Comment: How could I forget that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: Is there a way to expose the customizable settings of my view to IB so that I could for instance have the corner radius set directly in IB?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you only get what is available for a plain UIView.

Comment: Maybe there's a chance with these custom Key-Value pairs? I'll have to investigate that.